# Google cloud builder - Java version

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a build pipeline with Google cloud builder. I started off with something very simple: "mvn clean deploy", the cloudbuild.yaml I am using looks like this:

```
steps:
  # Build the application with maven
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    args: ['clean', 'deploy']
```

This seems to be working, the maven deploy is started but eventually I run into an error while compiling:

```
Step #1: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven- 
compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project codex-core-model: 
Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.9 -> [Help 1]
```

My project is written in java 9, so I will have to compile it using jdk9. Apparently the mvn builder uses jdk8, I checked for certainty using "mvn --version" and had these results:

```
Step #1: Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017- 
04-03T19:39:06Z)
Step #1: Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Step #1: Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Step #1: Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Step #1: Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
Step #1: OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-130-generic", arch: "amd64", 
family: "unix"
```

My question: Is there an easy way to make this builder use jdk9 instead of jdk8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no available Cloud Builder image in GCP with Java 9, you can see the latest source [right here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders).

But you can always submit your [own building steps](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps). If you check the Cloud Build for Maven, you can see that you will need to build first, your own `mvn` image, like [this one](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven), pushed into `gcr.io`.

After that, you can push this builder and use it in your pipeline.

---

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven
The repo doesn't seem to contain Java 9 anymore.